# How to create ASN.1 Sequence without NamedType?

Tags: python, asn.1

I'm trying to write client-side digital timestamping program and stuck in creating the timestamping request (.tsr) file.

Following is the real format of .tsr file after it's decoded (based on RFC3161)

```
Sequence:
 field-0=1
 field-1=Sequence:
  field-0=Sequence:
   field-0=2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3
   field-1=

  field-1=0x899ca19e19047eb08841d0ed0e8fa19b504927fafc126e5b7f100de56549ccab4d66fe92db70aa5d99e276c1c39a21cc0166e037406a0d1644dc2103181d86f6
```

I'm using pyasn1 modules to replicate the format and get the following(before it's encoded to .tsr)

```
TimeStampReq:
 version=1
 messageImprint=MessageImprint:
  hashAlgorithm=AlgorithmIdentifier:
   algorithm=2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3

  hashedMessage=0x899ca19e19047eb08841d0ed0e8fa19b504927fafc126e5b7f100de56549ccab4d66fe92db70aa5d99e276c1c39a21cc0166e037406a0d1644dc2103181d86f6

 nonce=5580318124348686814
```

This is the code I've written which gave the latter format

```
"""
Timestamp request class
"""
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype, namedval, tag
from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Extensions, AlgorithmIdentifier


class MessageImprint(univ.Sequence):
    """
    A message imprint as defined per IETF RFC 3161
    """
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('hashAlgorithm', AlgorithmIdentifier()),
        namedtype.NamedType('hashedMessage', univ.OctetString())
    )


class TSAPolicyId(univ.ObjectIdentifier):
    pass


class TimeStampReq(univ.Sequence):
    """
    A timestamp request as defined per IETF RFC 3161
    """
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('version', univ.Integer(1)),
        namedtype.NamedType('messageImprint', MessageImprint()),
        namedtype.OptionalNamedType('reqPolicy', TSAPolicyId()),
        namedtype.OptionalNamedType('nonce', univ.Integer()),
        namedtype.DefaultedNamedType('certReq', univ.Boolean(False)),

        namedtype.OptionalNamedType('extensions', Extensions().subtype(
            implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassUniversal, tag.tagFormatSimple, 0)
        ))
    )
    tagSet = univ.Sequence.tagSet.tagImplicitly(
        tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatConstructed, 0))
```

What do I have to do in order to create the correct format of .tsr file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this and it's actually a stupid question.

The first one is decoded without using any ASN.1 format and and all the field areas are left unnamed.

The second one I decode it using the TimeStampReq format I've written in the first place hence all the fields are named.